# Error on running cron job for mailing process on CivicRM 4.7.8

Tags: civimail, joomla

Running the php cli for the mailing process, got the failure

```
Entity: job Action: process_mailing
Summary
Finished execution of Send Scheduled Mailings with result: Failure, Error message: API permission check failed for Group/get call; insufficient permission: require access CiviCRM
Details
Parameters parsed (and passed to API method): 
a:1:
Unknown macro: {s}
Full message: 
Finished execution of Send Scheduled Mailings with result: Failure, Error message: API permission check failed for Group/get call; insufficient permission: require access CiviCRM
```

Here is my command for the cli

php ../administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bin/cli.php -u user -p password -e Job -a execute

Running manually from the schedule job, CiviCRM » Administer CiviCRM » Scheduled Jobs, 
there is no failure

Similar problem/bugs has been mentioned here [CRM-17968](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-17968) (fixed 4.7.4)

I saw that the fix already patched in the civicrm 4.7.8. but the problem still persisted, and i did not yet found the solution.

Thank you

Comment: This is also a problem in 5.5.3 with Joomla using `cv api Job.execute`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check that:

- your command line specifies the -s parameter, as it is used by CiviMail (cf. https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Managing+Scheduled+Jobs#ManagingScheduledJobs-PHPclimethod)
- the user/password pair on the command line is for a valid Joomla user (log into the website with this exact username and password)
- that this user has at least the Access CiviCRM and Administer CiviCRM permissions in Joomla